# Android width:100% fix (website takeover issue)

Tags: android, html, css, skin

I'm making a website skin / takeover.

It looks good on all browsers except android, where the skin image css parameter (width: 100%) is seen as the screen width not as at least the website's width. So it doesn't wrap the website but stops at the device's screen width. Please see yourself, I cannot explain very good. **What can I do?**

The first image is the website loaded on galaxy S3 and the second image is the website a little scrolled to see the right side. Please edit my question if you have better words.

This is the temporary link until I will move it to the client: http://csengrosseto.digitalprimes.com

[image: first view] 
[image: scrolled view]

Comment: I have resolved this kind of problems since by being careful that all the content is responsive; sometimes adding a negative margin on the body; overflow-x: hidden on the body; putting a size in pixels on the meta viewport bellow;

Comment: reduce the width of the browser while in debugger/inspector and see which elements stick outside of the body. then try to make them responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

This is the version that also controls the zoom.